# Calling script on reboot only after MongoDB has started

Tags: startup, reboot, services

I'm using the @reboot option as a root cron to update MongoDB when we do a reboot of a EC2 instance.

The problem I have is MongoDB isn't loaded at the point the cron runs the script.

Where is the best place to run a post MongoDB start on server startup?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used the upstart /etc/init/mongodb.conf file and it worked well.